# How to end text composition session programmatically in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview, contenteditable

I am trying to end text composition session programmatically when user are typing some non-latin character in a contenteditable DIV area (let call it editor later) in UIWebView (a legacy view object in iOS SKD that embeds web content in my hybrid app, for some reason I need to use it instead of using WKWebView).

When a user types a few non-latin character using input method editor (IME), my app will suggest some domain specific text on the UI and user can select it.

However, I found that after user selecting those domain specific text by clicking native UI (a `UIButton`), and the app has called `document.exeCommand('insertText', false, 'my domain text')`, the editor was still in text composition session with a light-blue background on the text the user just input.

If the user pressed some key on the IME, `compositionend` Event will got called and the composition session will end.

However, I want to programmatically end it so that it would be a more reasonable user experience. And in other scenario I need to be able to first end the text composition session then input those domain specific text. Is it possible?

Here is the UI of my hybrid app:
[image: app UI]

I have try to dispatch a compositionupdate event to the editor, the event listener did got called but the light-blue background was still under the text which means the text composition session was not end.

Here is the code I have tried:

```
var editor = document.getElementByID("myContendteditableArea")

editor.addEventListener('compositionend', function(e) {
    console.log('text composition session end')
})

var event = new CompositionEvent('compositionend')

editor.dispatchEvent(event)
```

I also tried blue the editor programmatically, it did trigger the 'compositioned' event, how ever this will cause some unwanted animation and UI change.

Any help will be appreciate, thank you in advanced.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: This would be fantastic but I don't think it can be done..